# Relation between number of nodes in Spark Cluster and huge amount of unstructured data

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, bigdata

I have huge amount of data located in Amazon S3. I want to load this data into a Spark Cluster (on Amazon EMR) and do some processing/querying on the newly loaded data.

```
Following is the approximate overall data size:
No. of Rows : ~ 20 billion records
No. of Columns: 2 columns ( numeric id, long text )
```

Based on the above size of data, I would like to know how many node cluster would be good enough for processing/querying data with a reasonable response time. Any stats or figures for the nodes for such size of data would be appreciated.

Kindly let me know if any extra information is required apart from the above information.

Comment: it greatly depends on the sort and volume of the queries. you can start with a mid size cluster and a single query and check response times. this is your best option imho. the figures you gave are not enough to formulate a 'good' 'solid' answer

Comment: Zahiro - Could you please let me know what all figures/info will be required to make a guess on the number of nodes in a cluster. Thanks

Comment: It really greatly depends on the instance types you choose and configuration and the such. How much did you plan on spending?

Comment: Zahiro - There are no constraints on budget so we can choose any of the instance types but the response time for heavy queries with regular expressions should be less than a minute. The total size of the data files is 1.5 TB. If you can also indicate the relation between the number of nodes and the response time we are expecting involving the instance types would be really helpful - Thanks